Test Exception thrown in async Task
I try to test this async method:
public static async Task SimpleAsync()   
{    
    await Task.Delay(10);
    throw new Exception("Should fail.");  

}

with:
Assert.Throws<Exception>(async () => await AsyncUnderTest.SimpleAsync()); 

 

but NUnit doesn't run:

Async void methods are not supported

How should I test the exception in NUnit?
I wonder how to include the Task return value in the lambda expression?
This question is much clearer and educational then the chaotic so-called "duplicate" question.

you can use Assert.ThrowsAsync..

Indeed:
Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async Task () => await AsyncUnderTest.SimpleAsync());

or also:
Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await AsyncUnderTest.SimpleAsync());

So async void is allowed in the lambda expression when using ThrowsAsync it is not allowed when using Throws.

None of the lambdas in your answer is async void. They are both async Task.

the second one is async void
